# How to fix: error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'Estado' and 'Estado*')

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, arduino

I'm trying to make an array of objects dynamically but after try sometimes I can't. The relevant code is the next

The whole code is too long, to paste it all here, so I'll just post the relevant parts.

This is the State.h

```
#ifndef State_h
#define State_h

#include "Arduino.h"


class State{
    private: 
        char *idText;
    public: 
        Estado(String _idText);
        Estado();
        void setID();
        int id;
};
#endif
```

This is the State.cpp

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "Estado.h"

using namespace std;

Estado::Estado(String _idText){
    _idText.toCharArray(idText, _idText.length()+1);
    setID();
}

Estado::Estado(){}

void Estado::setID(){
    char* _id = strtok(idText,":");
    id = atoi(_id);
}
```

This is the main.ino

```
Satate *states;

void setup(){
    int sizeParameters;
    sizeParameters = //I get the user's size from keyboard and convert to int
    char parametersChar;
    parametersChar = //I get the user's string from keyboard and convert to char
    estados = new Estado[sizeParameters];

    char* token = strtok(parametrosChar, "-");
    int i = 0;
    while(token != NULL){
        estados[i] = new Estado(token);// Here I get the error
        i++;
        token = strtok(NULL,"-");
    }

    Serial.println(estados[0].id);
}
```

I'm waiting an array of objects

Comment: Tip: Try to avoid using C-style arrays and `new[]`. Instead use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and other Standard Library containers. These make memory management significantly easier and can be passed by reference with information on size intrinsically included.

Comment: Unrelated: `Estado` may need extra support functions to take care of `char *idText;` See the [Rule of Three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define an array of `Estado` with this:

```
 estados = new Estado[sizeParameters];
```

Each of those entries has a type of `Estado`.

Then you go and assign something of type `Estado*` as returned by `new`:

```
 estados[i] = new Estado(token);
```

That can't work. Either you need this:

```
 estados = new Estado*[sizeParameters];
```

Where those are pointers instead, or you need this:

```
 std::vector<Estado> estados;
```

And then add to it incrementally:

```
 estados.push_back(Estado(token));
```

The `push_back` approach is better because you don't need to plan ahead on what size array you need, you can just add as you find new things to add. In practice this is a lot less annoying than demanding the user state up-front how many things they're adding. You can figure that out when they're finished adding.

Comment: ` estados = std::vector<Estado>;` is not valid.

Comment: Given that there’s no copy constructor or assignment operator defined, and the defaults make a shallow copy of a `char*`, `estados.emplace_back(Estado(token));` might be better.